# Python wikipedia API and JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, json, wikipedia-api

I'm trying to use Python Wikipedia API to collect pages around one topic in a language I'm getting a `JSONDecodeError`.

**My code** (`linksfirst` has all the links in a Wikipedia page):

```
for i in range(len(linksfirst)):

    t = linksfirst[i]
    try:
      qz = wikipedia.page(t)
      fz = q.content
      qqz = q.links
      contentsfirstz.append(fz)
      linksfirstz.append(qqz)
    except wikipedia.exceptions.DisambiguationError as e:
      print("Error: {0}".format(e))
      countz = countz + 1
    except wikipedia.exceptions.PageError:
      continue
```

**My error**:

```
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-009d9c9dc4ec> in <module>()
      7     t = linkmodify[i]
      8     try:
----> 9      if ((wikipedia.page(t) == 0)):
     10         g =g+1
     11      else:
/Users/sima/anaconda/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    355             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    356         except StopIteration as err:
--> 357             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None   
    358         return obj, end
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What page is it trying to load when it gets the error?

Comment: I have the same issue. For me it is intermittent, which suggests that a 'wait and retry' approach is potentially a (non ideal) solution.